# which one to use : Web Services or WCF Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

We have a c#net windows application. now our company decided to develop a web application using asp.net to support some of the windows application functionality on the world wide web.
so we are going to deploy some services in our windows application an let the web application to use them.

**Which one is the better choice : deploying WCF services or Web services ?**

Comment: Wcf service is a web service.

Comment: In a nutshell: "Classic" ASP.NET Web services (asmx) are a little bit simpler to set up, but they are essentially deprecated. WCF seems to be the future-proof option.

Comment: Well put it this is way C++ is better C...WCF is better Web Services. but still it depends on your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Services is a name for services that are reachable over the web infrastructure. Classically that has meant SOAP services, but the last years REST and REST-style (JSON over HTTP but not employing full REST semantics) have grown more popular.

So first you have to choose what kind of API you want to expose: SOAP or JSON over HTTP.

Second, you need a suitable framework for implementing such a services for SOAP services WCF is the right choice. asmx services are deprecated. For JSON over HTTP you can use WCF, but WebApi is easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

WCF are more complex and powerful than ASMX. However, that also means it takes a lot more effort to write them and a lot more knowledge to handle them. ASMX are super easy to write. Unless you specifically need features in WCF, go with ASMX. That said, there's also the option of ASP.NET Web Api which is the most recent service framework. It's similar to ASMX but much smarter and nicer to work with. I would recommend Web Api if you can use it in your situation.